# install pytorch c++ api CUDA11.4 for ubuntu

Tags: c++, pytorch, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to use the PyTorch c++ API on an ubuntu 18.04. I've installed CUDA 11.4 and cuDNN 8.2.4.15. The source I'm compiling is available here. compiling CUDA with nvcc works and the cuDNN installation test succeeds. But I am unable to find a good documentation for installing and compiling projects with PyTorch c++ api on Ubuntu. Do you know any god ones?

system configurations:
OS: ubuntu 18.04 
GPU: 1 x NVIDIA Tesla P4
Machine Type: n1-standard-2 (2 vCPUs, 7.5 GB memory) on google cloud console
CUDA: 11.4
cuDNN: 8.2.4.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the next ones to install on Ubuntu 16, it can be helpful for you.

- [PyTorch C++ API Ubuntu Installation Guide](https://gist.github.com/mhubii/1c1049fb5043b8be262259efac4b89d5)
- [tutorial to compile and use pytorch on ubuntu 16.04](https://kezunlin.me/post/54e7a3d8/)

Also can it will be util to refer the official documentation to use [PyTorch c++](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_frontend.html) for Linux systems and the [GCPdocumentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/getting-started-pytorch).